# How to Solve 'SqlCommand' exists between in .net Core?

Tags: oracle, .net-core, system.data

I try use Oracle write in DLL then into my .NET Core program, but it appears the following error message：

```
This type 'SqlCommand' exists between 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

How to solve this error message?

The following is my code.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using msClinicTxSvc.ViewModels;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

namespace msClinicTxSvc.Models
{
    public class ImportService : IDisposable
    {
        public bool contest(ImportViewModel ctd)
        {
            if (ctd.Source_Type == "MSSQL")
            {
                try
                {
                    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlcon = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"Data Source =" + ctd.HIS_Server + "; Initial Catalog =" + ctd.HIS_DB + "; User ID = " + ctd.HIS_User + "; PassWord =" + ctd.HIS_PW + ";");
                    sqlcon.Open();
                    sqlcon.Close();
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (ctd.Source_Type == "MySQL")
            {
                try
                {
                    MySqlConnection mysql = new MySqlConnection("Data Source=" + ctd.HIS_Server + ";Database=" + ctd.HIS_DB + ";User Id=" + ctd.HIS_User + ";Password=" + ctd.HIS_PW + ";");
                    mysql.Open();
                    mysql.Close();
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=" + server + "/" + db + ";User Id=" + userid + ";Password=" + pw + ";");
                    con.Open();
                    con.Close();
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it can Connection to MSSQL,MySQL and Oracle.

Comment: Please show us your code. `System.Data.SqlClient` sounds like SQL Server but not Oracle Client.

Comment: You don't import any Oracle namespace. How can you use `OracleConnection`?

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit I tried add Oracle namespace,but it appears "A reference to type 'Component' indicates that it is defined in 'System' but is not found.". So, I write about the code of Oracle as a DLL through NuGet to join my program.

Comment: Which namespace did you try to add?

Comment: using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;